# Need help for MS Access Select Request using 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, select, inner-join

For a "products reservation system", I have 2 tables :

- "RD", for global reservations data (fieds: ID, CustomerID, Date, ...)
- "RP", for reserved products data per reservation (fields: ID, RD_ID, ProductID, Status, ...). RD_ID fits with the ID in RD table (field for joining). Status field can have these values: O, C, S.

I need to extract (with 2 Select instructions) the list of reservations and the number of reservations for which all products have status 'O' .

Data example for RP:

```
ID | RD_ID | ProdID | Status
----------------------------
1  | 1     | 100    | O
2  | 1     | 101    | O
3  | 1     | 102    | O
4  | 2     | 105    | O
5  | 2     | 100    | S
6  | 3     | 101    | C
7  | 3     | 102    | O
```

In this example, Select statement should return only RD_ID 1

For the number of ID, the following request does not work because it also includes reservations with products having different status:

```
SELECT COUNT(rd.ID) FROM rd INNER JOIN rp ON rp.RD_ID = rd.ID WHERE rp.Status = 'O';
```

Could you help me for the right Select statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT rd.ID,  COUNT(rd.ID) CountOfRD, status
FROM rd INNER JOIN rp ON rp.RD_ID
GROUP BY rd.ID, status

Comment: Thank you, but it does not fit with my needs: 2  different statements and only for status 'O' (I've updated my question).

Comment: @Chris, that sql looks good to me. What result do you get if you just remove the count? Surely you should only get rows (rd.ID) with status = 'O'. Maybe just swap the tables around in the query so it reads a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.* from your_table t
Where t.status = 'O'
  And not exists (select 1 from your_table tt
                   Where t.rd_id = tt.rd_id
                     And t.status != tt.status)
```

You can also use `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
Select rd_id
  From your_table t
Group by rd_id
Having sum(case when status <> 'O' then 1 end) > 0
```